# CORS Issue (.Net WebAPI) Working with GET but not POST?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api

.Net Framework project using WebApi. I'm having a strange issue with CORS.

I have a class, with a GET and POST method. They are decorated appropriately with . When i fire off to the GET, it works fine. When i try the POST, i get a cors access-control-allow-origin header missing.

Get:

```
    <EnableCors("*", "*", "GET")>
    <AllowAnonymous>
    <ResponseType(GetType(CallbackConfig))>
    Async Function GetCallbackConfig(ByVal id As String) As Task(Of IHttpActionResult)
        '// Does stuff then

        Return Ok(callbackConfig)
    End Function

    <EnableCors("*", "*", "POST")>
    <HttpPost>
    <AllowAnonymous>
    <ResponseType(GetType(CallbackEvent))>
    Async Function PostCallbackEvent(<FromBody> CallbackEvent As CallbackDTO) As Task(Of IHttpActionResult)
       '// Does POST stuff
    End Function
```

I've tried many combinations to get this working:

Web.Config

Removed:

```
  <!--<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />-->
```

Added:

```
<httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

When i made these changes, it fixed the POST request, but broke the GET with the browser complaining it was getting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value twice.

WebAPIConfig.vb

```
 Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
    ' Web API configuration and services
    Dim cors = New EnableCorsAttribute(origins:="*", headers:="*", methods:="GET, POST")
    config.EnableCors(cors)
    ' Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )
End Sub
```

Am i missing something simple here? Why would the OPTIONS header generate properly on GET but not POST? I've got some OWIN configuration, does that matter? I'm using the latest Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi package (5.2.9)